# @font-face not working on a client site?

Tags: asp.net, css, iis, xhtml, font-face

This is CSS code

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FuturaStdBook';
    src: url('site/font-face/futurastd-medium-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('site/font-face/futurastd-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('site/font-face/futurastd-medium-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('site/font-face/futurastd-medium-webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h2 {font-family:'FuturaStdBook', sans-serif}
```

**Can it be related to mime type?**

How can i ensure my path is right?

Comment: What MIME type does get served? What browser on what OS?

Comment: do we have to have mime type support for all font file extensions.

Comment: Are you sure, that on the client machines there is no font installed named '`☺`'? Sorry, couldn't resist.

Comment: It almost certainly is no MIME type related problem, mainly because there *are no* registered mime types for any font format. That's the main reason for the `format('')` thingy in the CSS spec.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're using IIS, you'll need to register a MIME type for the .eot extension.

1. In IIS Manager, in the IIS section, open the MIME Types configuration
2. Under "Actions", click "Add..."
3. Enter `.otf` in the extension box, and `application/octet-stream` in the MIME type box.
4. Click OK

You'll need to do this for each non-standard extension you use (`.ttf` is already registered, `.woff` is not), but that should do it!

Comment: I actually just went through this last week... IIS doesn't know how to serve the file, so the request just ends up a 404.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to get a bullet-proof CSS declaration for your custom font.

Answer (score 1):

The problem are the definitions of `font-weight` and `font-style` in your font-face declaration. Since `h2` elements are defined in a **bold** face by default, the font-face declaration is not taken into account for these elements (because the browser thinks, the font file is *for normal weighted* weight only, which is most probably true).

Solution: You need a second font-face declaration with `font-weight: bold` in it **or** you set h2 elements to have `font-weight:normal` and `font-style: normal`.

Comment: still not working. How can i confirm path is correct and font-face is loading properly , problem is something else?

Comment: Do you use Firebug? If yes, in the "network" tab, is the font ever downloaded? Is it the right URL?

Comment: ...and what are the response headers? You could update your question accordingly to help finding answers.

Comment: @Boldwyn - how to know using firebug net tab , font is downloading or not?

Comment: No info about font in response headers

Comment: "Since h2 elements are defined in a bold face by default, the font-face rule is not taken into account for these elements" ... this is not true at all. Any rule defined with a more specific selector (or same specificity, but defined after the original) will override any "default" rules. "default" rules are just stylesheets themselves that are shipped with the browser. This still counts even if the overriding rule is setting the same style. Styles do not get ignored because they're the same as another style though.

Comment: @DanielSchaffer apart from my 6 years younger self mixing up "rule" and "declaration", what do you want to tell me here? If he sets `font-family` on his `h2`, the computed `font-weight` is still `bold` in _all browsers_. A `@font-face`, that defines its font as `font-weight: normal` will subsequently get ignored in all compliant browsers. And this is exactly, what I state in my answer.

Comment: Oy, I need to stop commenting on SO after wine. Sorry, carry on.

Comment: Nah, commenting is fine. But if it starts with "this is not true at all", you'll likely get some hefty response compared to "help me spot the error, but I think..." ☺