# CSS-defined font not found

Tags: css, webfonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [@font-face not working on a client site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714429/font-face-not-working-on-a-client-site)

I have the following font files in this folder structure in my ASP.Net MVC web app:

-[root]

|-- Public

||--fonts

|||--NuvoWeb-Medi.eot

|||--NuvoWeb-Medi.woff

In my CSS file I have the following font declaration:

```
@font-face 
{
    font-family: NuvoWeb;
    src: url(/Public/fonts/NuvoWeb-Medi.eot);
}
@font-face 
{
    font-family: NuvoWeb;
    src: url(/Public/fonts/NuvoWeb-Medi.woff) format('woff');
}
```

However, when I run the app, Firebug returns the following error:

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://localhost:60194/Public/fonts/NuvoWeb-Medi.woff"

Please advise as to what I am missing in order to get this to work.

Comment: Have you tried to visit this url? Maybe there are no files?

Comment: As I said, I have those files in the indicated folder structure; They are definitely there when I open the folder in Windows Explorer.  And if I click on the link, I get this response: HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Comment: So files are in folder, but not served by server? And that is a server problem, not css, Am I right?

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714429/font-face-not-working-on-a-client-site

Comment: You could see this thread about fonts not rendering properly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692151/fonts-are-not-rendered-correctly-in-release-mode-but-is-working-on-debug-mode-i?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Found the solution [here](http://www.localwisdom.com/blog/2011/10/iis-7-web-config-change-for-html5-and-css3-mime-types/)...

The problem is that IIS doesn’t know how to serve these new files unless we tell it how. This can be easily done in the web.config’s in the web.config’s `<system.webServer>` section by adding the following snippet:

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/m4v" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="video/ogg" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".oga" mimeType="audio/ogg" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".spx" mimeType="audio/ogg" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svgz" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

Note that some of these extensions may already be handled in IIS (for me, .svg was fine). You either need to remove those maps from this section, or include additional `<remove>` lines like the one for .eot.

Comment: For some reason, adding these to my web.config for a site hosted within the Rackspace Cloud breaks all of my CSS, as if the CSS file is no longer recognized. Any clue why that would happen?

Comment: This is so making people's day. For some reason I was trying to add filehandler rule for OTF files.

Comment: Based on this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16708374) the MIME type for woff files is actually "application/font-woff".  I got a complaint from Chrome when I used "font/x-woff" that the server was transferring a font with the wrong MIME type.  I changed to "application/font-woff" and that complaint went away.

Answer (score 7):

Register the MIME type in `web.config` as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

This solves the problem.

Comment: if you can here me, then please tell me the way to update the web.config through ftp. I am new for IIS server. Or please tell me that "am I able to do it? or need ask to my web hosting support that?"

Answer (score 2):

public folder(css here) ---> font folder (font here -NuvoWeb-Medi.eot)

```
@font-face 
{
    font-family: 'NuvoWeb';
    src: url(fonts/NuvoWeb-Medi.eot);
}
```

you were missed quotation symbol font-family: 'NuvoWeb';