# @font-face issue. I can't seem to get it working

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I have a .otf font that won't load on any browser. I feel I've followed the @font-face rule so I'm very confused. It's on my portfolio site at the bottom, the social media buttons. They read as a f and an i but they should be a facebook and linkedin icon. Any ideas? Thanks

[my portfolio site](http://wrobbins.me)

Answer (score 0):

Font Squirrel has a fantastic generator.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

I'd recommend using it to generate your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Your resources aren't pulling up the socialico.otf font... Make sure it's in the right directory.

see: http://wrobbins.me/fonts/socialico.otf (404)

Comment: It's in the directory though. If you're in Chrome and select the resource it loads.

Comment: I still see an error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: If all resources seem to be in the right place, try: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator and see if maybe it's a font type dependency issue.

Comment: So you're in Chrome. Hit F12. Click Resources. Open wrobbins.me. Click on socialico.otf once. If you double-click it, then it has the 404 error. To me that means it's a server issue.

Comment: I'm using Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57
It's in the resource list because the user has it marked in the stylesheet that the browser should look for it. By clicking on the list item in the debugger window and getting a 404 error it means it's a browser issue (CSS structure, non-support of font-type, etc) or the resource really isn't there.

Comment: I think it's too late now. It looks like he's editing it. I promise it loaded though. I swear I'm not crazy; I didn't just see it in the directory. I saw the letters of the font.

Comment: I believe you ;) but did you see the letters of the font? or social network icons as the font package was supposed to contain?

Comment: The entire alphabet plus the numbers.

Comment: Yeah, seems like you were just seeing the default font format that Chrome uses to filter through. You should have seen this http://fontfabric.com/social-media-icons-pack/ inside of that font viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Your font url appears as not found for me too, so I did a quick Google and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361200/css-defined-font-not-found) sounds similar to your problem. Could be that you need to tell your site how to handle that particular file extension.

Answer (score -1):

In Chrome it says your font url isn't found.

**Edit**

I googled and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051826/font-face-problem-in-chrome) answer mentions it being a server problem.